FAT16 - creating a virtual hard drive and reading it - for some reason no data existing
I'm writing an operating system project. I'm developing my project linux mint in c++ and a bit of assembly (and compiling it using gcc and GAS) and running it in a qemu machine (I make a .iso file out of the compiled code which I load into a qemu machine).
I'm currently at the stage of writing a file system and for that I chose FAT16, because I have developed a disk interface (ATA PIO to be specific). The virtual hard drive, as well as the .iso file are loaded into the qemu machine. However, before loading the virtual hard drive into the qemu machine I first format it (using the tool GParted) to have one partition that spans over the entire disk and is FAT16 defined, in the following manner:
/usr/bin/qemu-img create -f qcow2 os-disl.qcow2 512M
    # Start GParted virtual machine to define ext2 partition
    /usr/bin/qemu-system-i386 -cdrom gparted-live-1.6.0-3-i686.iso -hda os-disk.qcow2 -boot d -m 512

Also, once the virtual hard drive exists I load it with my iso file into a new qemu machine:
/usr/bin/qemu-system-i386 -cdrom ./objects/mykernel.iso -drive file="$DISK_PATH",cache=none -boot d -m 512 -no-reboot -no-shutdown -d int -M smm=off -s

In the GParted virtual machine that opens I create a new partition table and then add a new partition, pictures included:

(I created a new partition table with the msdos option)



After creating the virtual hard disk, I want to perform read operations on it, and parse the data so that I could actually begin implemnting the file system.
I first implement disk communication interface in the following manner:
disk.h:
#pragma once
#include <types.h>
#include <port/port.h>

void printf(uint8_t* ltr, int flag);   
void printfHex(uint8_t key);
class ata
{
protected:
    bool master;
    Port16Bit dataPort;
    Port8Bit errorPort;
    Port8Bit sectorCountPort;
    Port8Bit lbaLowPort;
    Port8Bit lbaMidPort;
    Port8Bit lbaHiPort;
    Port8Bit devicePort;
    Port8Bit commandPort;
    Port8Bit controlPort;
public:
    
    ata(bool master, uint16_t portBase);
    ~ata();
    
    void Identify();
    void Read28(uint32_t sectorNum, int count = 512, uint8_t* ptr=nullptr);
    void Write28(uint32_t sectorNum, uint8_t* data, uint32_t count);
    void Flush();
    
    
};

disk.cpp:
#include <fat16/disk.h>


ata::ata(bool master, uint16_t portBase)
:   dataPort(portBase),
    errorPort(portBase + 0x1),
    sectorCountPort(portBase + 0x2),
    lbaLowPort(portBase + 0x3),
    lbaMidPort(portBase + 0x4),
    lbaHiPort(portBase + 0x5),
    devicePort(portBase + 0x6),
    commandPort(portBase + 0x7),
    controlPort(portBase + 0x206)
{
    this->master = master;
}

ata::~ata()
{
}
            
void ata::Identify()
{
    devicePort.Write(master ? 0xA0 : 0xB0);
    controlPort.Write(0);
    
    devicePort.Write(0xA0);
    uint8_t status = commandPort.Read();
    if(status == 0xFF)
        return;
    
    
    devicePort.Write(master ? 0xA0 : 0xB0);
    sectorCountPort.Write(0);
    lbaLowPort.Write(0);
    lbaMidPort.Write(0);
    lbaHiPort.Write(0);
    commandPort.Write(0xEC); // identify command
    
    
    status = commandPort.Read();
    if(status == 0x00)
        return;
    
    while(((status & 0x80) == 0x80)
       && ((status & 0x01) != 0x01))
        status = commandPort.Read();
        
    if(status & 0x01)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        uint16_t data = dataPort.Read();
        char *text = "  \0";
        text[0] = (data >> 8) & 0xFF;
        text[1] = data & 0xFF;
    }
}

void ata::Read28(uint32_t sectorNum, int count, uint8_t* ptr)
{
    if(sectorNum > 0x0FFFFFFF)
        return;
    
    devicePort.Write((master ? 0xE0 : 0xF0) | ((sectorNum >> 24) & 0x0F));
    errorPort.Write(0);
    sectorCountPort.Write(1);
    lbaLowPort.Write(sectorNum & 0x000000FF);
    lbaMidPort.Write((sectorNum & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
    lbaHiPort.Write((sectorNum & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
    commandPort.Write(0x20);
    
    uint8_t status = commandPort.Read();
    while (((status & 0x80) == 0x80) && ((status & 0x01) != 0x01))
        status = commandPort.Read();
        
    if (status & 0x01)
        return;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 2)
    {
        uint16_t wdata = dataPort.Read();
        
        ptr[i] = wdata & 0xFF;
        if (i + 1 < count)
            ptr[i + 1] = (wdata >> 8) & 0xFF;
    }
    
    for (int i = count + (count % 2); i < 512; i += 2)
        dataPort.Read();
}

void ata::Write28(uint32_t sectorNum, uint8_t* data, uint32_t count)
{
    if(sectorNum > 0x0FFFFFFF)
        return;
    if(count > 512)
        return;

    // Set the drive and LBA high 4 bits
    devicePort.Write((master ? 0xE0 : 0xF0) | ((sectorNum >> 24) & 0x0F));
    
    errorPort.Write(0);
    sectorCountPort.Write(1);
    lbaLowPort.Write(sectorNum & 0xFF); // LBA low byte
    lbaMidPort.Write((sectorNum >> 8) & 0xFF); // LBA mid byte
    lbaHiPort.Write((sectorNum >> 16) & 0xFF); // LBA high byte
    commandPort.Write(0x30); // Write sectors command
    
    // Wait until the drive is ready
    uint8_t status = commandPort.Read();
    while ((status & 0x80) && !(status & 0x08)) {
        status = commandPort.Read();
    }
    
    // Write the data
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 2)
    {
        uint16_t wdata = data[i];
        if (i + 1 < count)
            wdata |= ((uint16_t)data[i + 1]) << 8;
        dataPort.Write(wdata);
    }
    
    // Pad remaining data with zeros if count is less than 512
    for (int i = count + (count % 2); i < 512; i += 2)
        dataPort.Write(0x0000);
}

void ata::Flush()
{
    devicePort.Write( master ? 0xE0 : 0xF0 );
    commandPort.Write(0xE7);

    uint8_t status = commandPort.Read();
    if(status == 0x00)
        return;
    
    while(((status & 0x80) == 0x80)
       && ((status & 0x01) != 0x01))
        status = commandPort.Read();
        
    if(status & 0x01)
    {
        return;
    }
}

After creating the disk interface I create an instance of the class and begin read operations:
ata ata0m(true, 0x1F0);
ata0m.Identify();

FAT16.h:
#pragma once
#include <types.h>
#include <fat16/disk.h>
#include <stddef.h>
extern ata ata0m;
typedef struct 
{
    // The mbr contains three different parts
    // Boot code - first 446 bytes
    // Partition tables - 4 entries with each sized 16 bytes that describe different partitions on the disk 
    // The struct describes a single entry
    uint8_t  bootIndicator;
    uint8_t  startHead;
    uint8_t  startSector;
    uint8_t  startCylinder;
    uint8_t  partitionType;
    uint8_t  endHead;
    uint8_t  endSector;
    uint8_t  endCylinder;
    uint32_t relativeSector;
    uint32_t totalSectors;
} __attribute__((packed)) MBR_PartitionEntry;


typedef struct 
{
    // Implement mbr strcure, we will load this into sector 0
    uint8_t  bootstrap[446];
    MBR_PartitionEntry partitionTable[4];
    uint16_t signature; // 0x55AA
} __attribute__((packed)) MBR;


typedef struct 
{
    // The first sector of each partition is called the boot sector and contains some metadata about the partition and the file system
    uint8_t  BS_jmpBoot[3];
    uint8_t  BS_OEMName[8];
    uint16_t BPB_BytsPerSec; // 512
    uint8_t  BPB_SecPerClus; // 8 
    uint16_t BPB_RsvdSecCnt;
    uint8_t  BPB_NumFATs; // usually 2
    uint16_t BPB_RootEntCnt; // garbage values, must be set
    uint16_t BPB_TotSec16; 
    uint8_t  BPB_Media;
    uint16_t BPB_FATSz16;
    uint16_t BPB_SecPerTrk;
    uint16_t BPB_NumHeads;
    uint32_t BPB_HiddSec;
    uint32_t BPB_TotSec32;
    uint8_t  BS_DrvNum;
    uint8_t  BS_Reserved1;
    uint8_t  BS_BootSig;
    uint32_t BS_VolID;
    uint8_t  BS_VolLab[11];
    uint8_t  BS_FilSysType[8];
} __attribute__((packed)) FAT16_BootSector;



void Read_MBR();
void readBootSector(); // Use ata_read_sector  
FAT16_BootSector parseBootSector(uint8_t* bootSectorBuffer); // Receive the data from previous function and parse

// MBR information about our FAT16 partition
extern uint32_t lba_start;
extern uint32_t lba_limit;
extern uint8_t partition_type;

// Boot sector information about FAT16
extern uint16_t bytes_per_sector;
extern uint8_t sectors_per_cluster;
extern uint16_t reserved_sectors;
extern uint8_t number_of_FATs;
extern uint16_t root_entries;
extern uint16_t total_sectors;

extern uint16_t sectors_per_FAT;
extern uint32_t root_directory_sectors;
extern uint32_t first_data_sector;
extern uint32_t total_clusters;
// Calculate the starting sector of the FAT and root directory
extern uint32_t fat_start_sector;
extern uint32_t root_dir_start_sector;

FAT.cpp:
#include <fat16/fat16.h>
// This is the beggining of the file system - which is FAT16


MBR mbr;
FAT16_BootSector boot_sector;
uint32_t lba_start;
uint32_t lba_limit;

void Read_MBR()
{
    // Write to the first sector of the disk - which is the MBR
    // In: struct sized 512 that includes a partition table
    // Out: None

    ata0m.Read28(0, 512, (uint8_t*)&mbr); // Load MBR into mbr struct, this will actually load correctly the data

    if (mbr.signature != 0xaa55) printf((uint8_t*)"error", 0);

    MBR_PartitionEntry* firstPartition = &(mbr.partitionTable[0]); // pointer to the first partition table entry

    uint32_t lba_start = firstPartition->relativeSector; // Actual beggining of our partition

    uint32_t lba_limit = firstPartition->totalSectors; // Size of partition

    uint8_t partition_type = firstPartition->partitionType;

    printfHex(partition_type);
    printf((uint8_t*)"\n",0);

    // Purpose of function: to set up values in the lba global variables  
}


void readBootSector() 
{
    // Implement reading of the boot sector using your disk I/O functions

    // First we read the entire sector into the bootsector structure
    // Then parse it anf gain the useful data
    ata0m.Read28(lba_start, 512, (uint8_t*)&boot_sector);

    uint16_t bytes_per_sector = boot_sector.BPB_BytsPerSec;
    uint8_t sectors_per_cluster = boot_sector.BPB_SecPerClus;
    uint16_t reserved_sectors = boot_sector.BPB_RsvdSecCnt;
    uint8_t number_of_FATs = boot_sector.BPB_NumFATs;
    uint16_t root_entries = boot_sector.BPB_RootEntCnt;
    uint16_t total_sectors = boot_sector.BPB_TotSec16;
    if (total_sectors == 0) 
    {
        total_sectors = boot_sector.BPB_TotSec32;
    }
    uint16_t sectors_per_FAT = boot_sector.BPB_FATSz16;
    uint32_t root_directory_sectors = ((root_entries * 32) + (bytes_per_sector - 1)) / bytes_per_sector;
    uint32_t first_data_sector = reserved_sectors + (number_of_FATs * sectors_per_FAT) + root_directory_sectors;
    uint32_t total_clusters = (total_sectors - first_data_sector) / sectors_per_cluster;

    // Calculate the starting sector of the FAT and root directory - this is the important thing
    uint32_t fat_start_sector = lba_start + reserved_sectors;
    uint32_t root_dir_start_sector = fat_start_sector + (number_of_FATs * sectors_per_FAT);


    printfHex(sectors_per_cluster);
    printf((uint8_t*)"\n",0);


    printfHex(number_of_FATs);
    printf((uint8_t*)"\n",0);

    
}


I first call Read_MBR and then call readBootSector. Inside these function I use print statements that result in the following output:

This is weird for me. From what I understood I'm supposed to see different values in variables like number_of_FATs (which is typically 2). For that reason I looked at a hexdump of the virtual hard disk file (os-disk.qcow2) using the following command:
sudo dd if=/dev/loop0 bs=4096 count=1 | hexdump -C

before that I mounted the virtual hard disk to my machine using
sudo losetup -P /dev/loop0 os-disk.qcow2
sudo fdisk -l /dev/loop0
sudo dd if=/dev/loop0 bs=512 count=1 | hexdump -C

The last command looks at the 512 first bytes of the file. The output I got was:
fridkin@fridkin-virtual-machine:~/os/yb-os$ sudo dd if=/dev/loop0 bs=512 count=1 | hexdump -C
00000000  51 46 49 fb 00 00 00 03  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |QFI.............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10  00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00  |............ ...|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01  00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000060  00 00 00 04 00 00 00 70  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.......p........|
00000070  68 03 f8 57 00 00 01 80  00 00 64 69 72 74 79 20  |h..W......dirty |
00000080  62 69 74 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |bit.............|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 01 63 6f 72 72 75 70  |..........corrup|
000000b0  74 20 62 69 74 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |t bit...........|
000000c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 02 65 78 74 65 72 6e  |..........extern|
000000e0  61 6c 20 64 61 74 61 20  66 69 6c 65 00 00 00 00  |al data file....|
000000f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 03 63 6f 6d 70 72 65  |..........compre|
00000110  73 73 69 6f 6e 20 74 79  70 65 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ssion type......|
00000120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000130  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 04 65 78 74 65 6e 64  |..........extend|
00000140  65 64 20 4c 32 20 65 6e  74 72 69 65 73 00 00 00  |ed L2 entries...|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 6c 61 7a 79 20 72  |..........lazy r|
00000170  65 66 63 6f 75 6e 74 73  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |efcounts........|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000190  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  02 00 62 69 74 6d 61 70  |..........bitmap|
000001a0  73 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |s...............|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  02 01 72 61 77 20 65 78  |..........raw ex|
000001d0  74 65 72 6e 61 6c 20 64  61 74 61 00 00 00 00 00  |ternal data.....|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.0314317 s, 16.3 kB/s
00000200

This doesn't look right at all to me. Therefore I suspect I made a mistake somewhere while formatting the file.. Does anyone have an idea?
I would have expected to at least see the MBR signature which is 0x55AA at the last two bytes of the file. Thanks again!
For those interested, here is a link to the github repository: https://github.com/yfrandom2020/yb-os/tree/main

"before that I mounted the virtual hard disk to my machine". No you did not. This is a QCOW formatted file, not raw disk drive. QEMU understands that format of disk image, Linux does not. You are looking at file header, not the actual drive contents.

Multiple problems here.
1. Error in the code
uint32_t lba_start;

void Read_MBR()
{
    /// ...
    uint32_t lba_start = firstPartition->relativeSector; // Actual beggining of our partition
   /// ...
}

Do you see the issue here?
How to avoid this in the future? Switch on compiler warnings. If they are switched on, read them. gcc would've warned you about this error if you'd let it. Better yet, turn warnings into errors. -Wall -Werror is a good way to live - you get some annoying warnings to deal with, but it is much better than the alternative of having to hunt for some stupid mistakes. Also, remove -fpermissive.
Also, good idea to learn how to debug your kernel. Its not that hard a thing to do for your current setup and it might help immeasurely if you know how to do debug. Just add -s -S to your qemu command so it'll wait for gdb to connect to it, run qemu, run gdb -ex "target remote :1234" objects/mykernel.bin, setup some breakpoint wherever you want to hook into (let's say break initializers()), and start the loading process with cont.
2. Qcow file format
Told you once, telling again now. Use raw disk drive format instead of qcow2. qcow is a nice format to use for your virtual machines in general but it is not that transparent to use outside of qemu. Use raw disk image for your OS development - you can mount it using loop device, you can dd it, you can fire up fricking hex editor and see what is actually there. If you'd use it, you might've found out the third issue:
3. There is no FAT filesystem
Like the title says. You have created the partition but never formatted it. There is no FAT metadata to be read.
